# how to apply brightness ,contrast ,gamma on image while moving slider in iOS?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

Hi i am using GPUImagefilters for applying brightness on image.But it does not work.i could not find that problem where it is.my code is like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.slider.hidden=YES;
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 1.0;
slider.value = 0.1;
}
- (IBAction)brightnessClicked:(id)sender
{
self.slider.hidden=NO;

}
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(id)sender
{

image_p=[[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:image3];

GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter1 = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

[image_p addTarget:filter1];

[image_p processImage];
[(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)filter setBrightness:[(UISlider *)sender value]];

//    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([filter1 imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

//self.thirdImgView.image = [image3 brightness:(1+value-0.5)];
//    self.thirdImgView.image = ;

}
```

if its not possible to get GPUImagefilters tell me any other way.I tried in more ways but it does not work so please anybody suggest me how to do this.any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{        
   [sliderChange setMinimumValue:-0.5];

   [sliderChange setMaximumValue:0.5];

   [sliderChange setValue:0.0];

   brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

}

-(IBAction)upDateSliderValue:(id)sender 
{

   GPUImagePicture *fx_image;

   fx_image = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];

   [brightnessFilter setBrightness:self.sliderChange.value];

   [fx_image addTarget:brightnessFilter];

   [fx_image processImage];

   UIImage *final_image = [brightnessFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

   self.selectedImageView.image = final_image;

}
```

Comment: It returned nil `[brightnessFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)getNewImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image withBrightness:(CGFloat)brightnessValue
{
        // pass the image through a brightness filter
        GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];

        GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
        [brightnessFilter setBrightness:brightnessValue];
        [blurFilter addTarget:brightnessFilter];

        [stillImageSource processImage];
        return [brightnessFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
}
```

to make it darker than default you have to pass negative values.

Comment: k Thank you soo much for relying me LoVo..but how can i call that method? when i move the slider ..i called like this but getting error ..- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(id)sender
{getNewImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image withBrightness:

Comment: sorry i  [ self getNewImageFromImage:withBrightness:];

Comment: image_p = [self getNewImageFromImage:withBrightness:];

Comment: getting an error like undeclared Identifier withBrightness

Comment: DUDE don't just copy and paste, you have to pass an IMAGE and a FLOAT image_p = [self getNewImageFromImage:ORIGINAL_IMAGE(image_p in your case) withBrightness:VALUE_OF_YOUR_SLIDER];

Comment: - (UIImage *)getNewImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image withBrightness:(CGFloat)brightnessValue
{
    // pass the image through a brightness filter
    image_p = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image3];

    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

Comment: [brightnessFilter setBrightness:slider.value];

    [image_p  addTarget:brightnessFilter];

    [image_p processImage];

    return [brightnessFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
}

Comment: - (IBAction)sliderMoved:(id)sender
{
    
   image_p = [self getNewImageFromImage:image3 withBrightness:slider.value];
    
}

Comment: i written like this but no change ..i am facing same issue